# React native in app developers menu not working on Real device

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

Shaking device is not opening the developers menu.

I run the following command to open the menu

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
```

Output is

```
Error: TV display id Invalid, will send event to default displayId
```

So how to open/enable in app developer menu on android device ?

React native : 0.44.0
Android device : Lenovo k4 note

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue so what I did is, I uninstalled the app and installed it again. After doing it try to shake the device you will get into the developer menu.